# How to start a new webdriver session (driver.start_session) keeping the "headless mode" active in Selenium with python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I've this issue:
I created a custom class to handle the first initialization of my webdriver.
It includes some methods and I re-used this script into a new software.
However in this application I do need to restart the webdriver after a driver.quit command.
I can re-load the capabilities I need along with the firefox profile I already had in use; but I cannot set the options again: my webdriver open an unwanted window.

```
# here my selenium control class which starts in headless mode if global variable "headless" is set to true
headless = True
class SeleniumCtrl:
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('-headless')
    cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
    cap["marionette"] = True
    cap['loggingPrefs'] = {'browser': 'ALL'}
    # other lines which the profile is set in....

    if headless:
        browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile, capabilities=cap, firefox_options=options, executable_path="/my path/geckodriver")
    else:
        browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile, capabilities=cap, executable_path="/my path/geckodriver")


# here my call to initialize the driver control and also the driver itself, ready to use
driver_ctrl = SeleniumCtr() #my custom class
driver_plain = driver-ctrl.browser

# here my function to reset the web driver session
def reset_session:
    # here some line to set the profile and the capabilities
    cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
    cap["marionette"] = True
    cap['loggingPrefs'] = {'browser': 'ALL'}

    driver_plain.firefox_profile.set_preference(pref, val)
    current_url = driver_plain.current_url
    driver_plain.close()
    driver_plain.start_session(cap, profile) # here I should be able to set the "headless" opt again, but I don't know how
```

Of course I can re-write the SeleniumCtrl class code to get able to re-initialize the web driver, creating a new object, however I'd like to avoid this, if it's reasonable.

Thanks in advance